# The initial fis generated by genfis1 in matlab directly using evalfis produces an output of 0

Tags: matlab

I have tested the fis generated by genfis1. After anfis training, fis can achieve better fitting output, but before anfis training, the fis fitting output is 0. Why is this? According to my understanding, fis without anfis training should only be the difference between the fitting accuracy and the trained fis, rather than the output should be all 0

I would like to be able to tell me whether there is a problem with my code that causes the output to be 0, or whether MATLAB itself produces this effect, and please tell me the difference between fis before and after training

```
% Generates training data
Data = [rand (100, 1) 10 * rand (100, 1) - 5 rand (100, 1));


% Sets the number and type of membership functions

numMFs = [3 5];

mfType = 'gbellmf';


Generate fuzzy inference system

fismat = genfis1(data, numMFs, mfType);


Extract input data and actual output

inputs = data(:, 1:2);

actualOutput = data(:, 3);


% Calculate fuzzy output

fisOutput = evalfis(inputs, fismat);


% Draw an image of the fuzzy output versus the actual output

scatter3(inputs(:, 1), inputs(:, 2), actualOutput, 'filled', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b');

hold on;

scatter3(inputs(:, 1), inputs(:, 2), fisOutput, 'filled', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r');

xlabel('Input 1');

ylabel('Input 2');

zlabel('Output');

legend('Actual Output', 'Fuzzy System Output');
```